Geometry Nodes -> Points to Volume - Mesh is not showing in Preview/Viewport Render Mode
I am using a Procedural Cloud generator but for some unknown reason the object with the Geometry Node modifier refuses to show any of the resulting geometry at all and it simply won't show.
I am using a volumetric material in both the mesh in itself and through a Set Material Node in the GN tree.
This is what both meshes look like with the cloud material I'm using.

Here's a picture of the actual node tree, by the way

Why is this happening?
For some weird reason it shows in EEVEE with no issues at all.
Here is a link with the .blend file for the project:
enter link description here
The blend file link for this project
The blend file link so you can check it
EDIT 01: So it seems Gordon Brinkmann got us a neat clue, it seems to be a problem with my own installed version of Blender. I'm using it on Steam by the way, since I like the metrics.
I might want to verify the cache or something, it might fix it.
I've tried using the actual Render and not the preview, but the Suzanne is nowhere to be seen at all unfortunately.
Gordon is correct with the Viewport Downgrade option but I aim to see something at all not an upgraded or downgraded version of my work.


I guess if it shows in EEVEE it's probably not a visibility setting problem. But I'll ask anyway: is the rendered image a real render result or is it the rendered preview in the viewport? On my PC it works with my setup, however in your screenshots I cannot see any material setup, I have no idea which values you are using for the volumetrics since I can see only connections plugged into the node, no values. The Outliner could be interesting for visibility settings, but as I already said that's probably not it. Your file could be helpful too, anyway we need more information.

Sure! I've edited the question, now it has a dropbox link.

Any guesses on this?
Here's a link again for the project:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/qneqdp8j7wfm8rrq7ei52/Procedural-Clouds.blend?rlkey=glfk8ldr1h87vp7th0e0tfsjw&st=e3ybaorm&dl=0

Stop posting the link over and over again! One time is enough. Apart from that, do not rely on external sources for your files, because once links are broken or expired it makes them useless in the question. Instead upload them here https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions to edit them into your question.

I do not see nothing on the left side when rendering. Maybe you are using a version that is not compatible with the nodetree, in my Blender 4.3 it works, also in 4.1.1 and 4.2.3, in earlier versions it does not work however there I get no volume on the GN object at all, neither viewport nor render. So I do not know if you have changed anything since you've been posting the original screenshots, but this is how it looks in my 4.3 viewport:

And this is how it looks after I rendered it, it's not empty on the left side, there is another Suzanne:

The difference why the viewport shows a sphere and the render a monkey is easily explained. In the settings of the Geometry Nodes modifier there is a value "Viewport Downgrade", hovering the mouse over there is a tooltip which says:
"This setting reduces the quality resolution of the clouds only for the viewport. It does that by dividing it and keep the maximum resolution on the render time."

The value is set to 4, so I guess since it's a divisor by setting it to 1 it should give the same resolution in the viewport as for the render - and that's exactly what it does:


Ok I seem to have found the solution.
I'm using Blender through Steam, asked Steam to verify Integrity of Installed Files and now Blender works properly.
Bummer, the solution was rather simple. Cudos for Gordon for giving me a hunch, though. Very helpful pointer!
Reminder:
Go to Steam > Library > Blender > Right-Click > Properties >
Verify Integrity of Installed Files
Thanks a lot, folks
